# Selenium proxy connection, why ip does not change?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I want to connect to proxy servers with python and selenium but I think there is a mistake because every time I connect to a proxy and check my IP I see the same. However I don't get any error

```py
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", str(proxy['ip']))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy['port']))
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, options = options)
```

I am really looking forward to find a way to change my IP while surfing the web with selenium.

Comment: some proxy servers send header with your real IP - not all proxies are anonymous.

Comment: is there a way to change the header in a way that it sends the fake ip address?

Comment: this header is added by proxy so you don't have access to this header. You have to search proxies which don't add it. Read [What is the proxy anonymity?](https://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html) in Proxy FAQs

Comment: there can be also other problem - server may have blacklist with IPs of proxies and check if you use this IP from this list. And server can block your requests even if proxy doesn't show your real IP.

Comment: I checked my ip with https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I don't think this site black list proxies.

Comment: All in all, thank you

Comment: this page may not use blacklist because it doesn't need it but if you try to use proxy to scrape from Google then Google may use its blacklist and block your requests.